# Change color of selected item in Select [Material UI]

Tags: material-ui

Trying to change the default dark-blue color of a material-ui select is giving me some issues.

E.g. on this sandbox[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mc1X.png), how does one override the blue color on the "Native Select"? I tried overriding it with the below, but to no avail. It changes the color when hovered over, but when I select it, it goes back to being blue.

```
  selected: {
    '& option:hover': {
      background: 'red',
    },
    '& option:active': {
      background: 'red',
    },
    '& option:focus': {
      background: 'red',
    }
  }
```

1
https://codesandbox.io/s/cwvg4?file=/demo.js

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement here is to change the color to 'red' for depicting error, then you can pass 'error' prop in the 'select' component as true. If that's not the case, I have made a workaround for your use case.

```
 const styles = theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 120
  },
  icon: {
    fill: "red"  //coloring the dropdown arrow icon
  },
  select: {
    // color: "red", //can be used to give color to options in the dropdown 
    "& option": {
      background: theme.palette.background.paper
    },
    "&:before": {
      borderColor: "red"
    },
    "&:after": {
      borderColor: "red"
    }
  }
});
```

Also, for the color of your label 'Age' ( in your CodeSandBox )

```
<InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple" style={{ color: "red" }}>
```

Didn't completely get your requirement, but this should help you with the coloring part.Also, this might not be the prettiest solution, but will get the work done!

Check out the demo for the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-sunset-oyhm8?file=/src/demo.js:977-1042

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Indeed I seem to have messed up the codepen url - with the one I pasted, the question doesn't make much sense :/  I meant the native select in this codepen right here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cwvg4?file=/demo.js.
I'll edit the original post, too.

Thanks again for your help attempt!